# Nested radion button form array. Able to select all radio buttons angular reactive form array

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

In angular,I have nested formarrays.Each form array can dynamicaly add many radio buttons.Inside one form array,I am able to select all radio buttons. How to select one radio button in one form array.?

```
   <table class="wk-table" formArrayName="inlineChoices">
      <td>
       <div class="wk-fill-inthe-blank-outer" formArrayName="answerChoice">
                  <div class="wk-row">
                    <div
                      class="wk-fill-inthe-blank-inner"
                      *ngFor="
                        let choice of inlineChoices['controls'][i].get(
                          'answerChoice'
                        )['controls'];
                        let inx = index
                      "
                      [formGroupName]="inx"
                    >
                      <fieldset>
                        <legend class="hidden-text">wk</legend>
                        <input
                          type="radio"
                          id="correct{{ i }}"
                          (change)="onRadioSelection($event, i, inx)"
                          name="correct"
                          value="{{ i + 1 }}"
                          formControlName="correct"
                          [checked]="true"
                        />
    
                        <input
                          formControlName="label"
                          type="text"
                          class="wk-fill-inthe-blank-ans"
                        />
                      </fieldset>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </td>
            </table>
```